# Image get zoom after sharing the image on whats app

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code for sharing the image on button click..when i share the image on whatsapp, after download it will be in zoom size. I don't got any solution for it.

```
pagelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
pagelayout.buildDrawingCache();
bitmap_one = pagelayout.getDrawingCache();


Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap_one.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + separator + "ImageDemo.jpg");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// pagelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (Uri.fromFile(file)));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
pagelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: what was  happened for other applications?

Comment: its a whatsapp application problem not ours

Comment: for other applications it will posted an download ok...an not zoom..@farazkhonsari

Comment: normally it is happens in whatsapp don't worry. happy coding

Comment: ohk....its whats app problem....not my code??- @SahdevRajput74

Comment: sent a square in size image and check it should be proper at this time

Comment: not your problem don't worry

Comment: thank you ....@SahdevRajput74